# How to interface a DOM object when a link is pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, dom

I am on http://localhost:8000/index.html

When I press a link, I want it to go to localhost:8006/someAddress and select element with id='157579' AND press button with id='1787' which will cause an iframe further down my html to show something different.

I have made some pseudo code that somewhat shows what I want, but I am having a hard time converting it into something functional:

```html
<body>
<script> 
    function Scenario1() {
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            GoTo http://localhost:8006/SomeAddress
            document.getElementById("157579").Select
            Button("1787").Press    
        }
    }
</script>
</body>
```

Is this possible to do, or is there an alternative? I understand that I have to do something with AJAX or jQuery or something similar, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use jquery click event when in your onload is triggered like  `$('#157579').click();`

```js
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();


xhr.open('GET', '/article/xmlhttprequest/example/load');


xhr.send();


xhr.onload = function() {
  if (xhr.status != 200) { 
    alert(`Error ${xhr.status}: ${xhr.statusText}`); 
  } else { 
    $('#157579').click();
  }
};

xhr.onprogress = function(event) {
  if (event.lengthComputable) {
    alert(`Received ${event.loaded} of ${event.total} bytes`);
  } else {
    alert(`Received ${event.loaded} bytes`);
  }

};

xhr.onerror = function() {
  alert("Request failed");
};
```